How to stop .navigationDestination from rendering twice in SwiftUI?
I have a .navigationDestination inside of a NavigationStack that is inside of a TabView that when it opens the view the .task{} runs twice or three times. How do I stop this?
(Edited)
Here is some code that should reproduce it. To make it happen you have to switch tabs once. It won't happen if you just click on the books in Tab One right after launch. This problem seems to only happen in a TabView.
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var router = Router()
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            content
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab One", systemImage: "house")
                }
            content
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab Two", systemImage: "house")
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(router)
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.navigationPath) {
            HomeView()
                .navigationDestination(for: BookViewModel.self) { book in
                    BookView(book: book)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var router: Router
    @State private var books: [BookViewModel] = [.init(id: 1, title: "First Book", yearPublished: 2023), .init(id: 2, title: "Second Book", yearPublished: 2024)]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(books) { book in
                Button(book.title, action: {
                    router.navigationPath.append(book)
                })
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("First View")
    }
}

The .task{} here is the one that is called multiple times.
struct BookView: View {
    @ObservedObject var book: BookViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(book.title)
            Text("\(book.yearPublished)")
        }
        .navigationTitle(book.title)
        .task {
            print("opened")
        }
    }
}

final class Router: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var navigationPath: NavigationPath = .init()
    
    // ... Other functions
    
}

public class BookViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable {
    public let id: Int64
    @Published public var title: String
    @Published public var yearPublished: Int64
    // ... other vars
    
    init(id: Int64, title: String, yearPublished: Int64) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.yearPublished = yearPublished
    }
    
    public static func == (lhs: BookViewModel, rhs: BookViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(title)
    }
}


You say you have problems when you call ... .onAppear{} or  .task{}, but you don’t show any code relating to those.
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.
Some (minimal) code we can compile and run.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I added code that you can run that should cause the issue.

Note, you have two separate NavigationStack controlled by the same router.
So a change in one will also trigger a change in the other.
With ObservableObject you should always declare them
@StateObject .... Currently you have @State private var books: [BookViewModel] = ....
Restructure your code, make struct Book: ... and
class BookViewModel: ObservableObject { @Published var books: [Book] = .... Use different route for each NavigationStack.
See Apple Monitoring data

Thanks. I think I understand what is going on.

@StateObject is for loading or saving model data it's not for view data that's the job of View structs and State/Binding.
Navigation is designed to have a destination per data type, e.g.
.navigationDestination(for: Book.self) { book in
}
.navigationDestination(for: Author.self) { author in {
}

Etc..
And they don't all need to be in the same View. Also recomputation of these view data structs is not "rendering" and it's negligible performance wise because they are values so you shouldn't worry about it same way you wouldn't care about ints.

I edited my question with some runnable code. On your ViewModel comment, I believe that it would be better to call them DataModels but this is how the previous Dev did it. But I am open to suggestions.
